# How would I append an element to another element using a directive that uses binding attributes?

Tags: angular

I am creating a directive in Angular 7 that will place a magnifying glass icon in an input. I'd like it to work like this:

`<input type="text" search-icon />`

I am currently using font-awesome. To use an icon in font-awesome, you would import the icon into a component and then use that icon as the attribute in the icon tag:

```
import {faSearch} from 'fontawesome/some/dir';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    template: '<fa-icon [icon]="faSearch"></fa-icon>',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent {
    faSearch = faSearch;

    constructor() {}
}
```

The problem I am facing is not knowing how I would add the attribute `[icon]` to the `<fa-icon>` element.

I have tried creating the `<fa-icon>` element like this:

`const icon = document.createElement('fa-icon');`

However, I don't know how I would add the `[icon]` attribute. It needs to be bound to the `faSearch` variable so it can be rendered.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import {faSearch} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faSearch';

@Directive({
    selector: '[search-icon]'
})
export class SearchDirective {

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private elRef: ElementRef) {
        const icon = document.createElement('fa-icon');
        renderer.setAttribute(icon, '[icon]', 'faSearch');
        renderer.insertBefore(elRef.nativeElement.parentNode, icon, elRef.nativeElement);
    }

}
```

I expect this to bind the `faSearch` variable to the `[icon]` attribute, but I get this console error:

`InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[icon]' is not a valid attribute name`

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

The accepted answer actually made me think of doing this differently, which is why i accepted it. I ended up importing font-awesome in my index.html file and just created an `i` tag where I set the class based on the icon I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how applicable this is for you, but the way I have been doing it is like this

```
<mat-form-field>
  <button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon mat-icon-button
          matPrefix>filter_list</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <input type="text"
         [(ngModel)]="value"/>
  <button mat-icon-button matSuffix>
    <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="myFunction()">close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

Note the that `mat-prefix` and `mat-suffix` are needed for left/right alignment.